# JQuery numbered ids

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a couple of buttons to switch between red and green, I've looked through the Jquery documentation, but I can't seem to figure this one out.

You can see in my code snippet, that when I click on the button, all the buttons turn a different colour.

Also there must be a shorter way of doing this, not they way I've bulked it out.

Any help will be amazing!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".but").click( function(){
  $("#sq_0").css("background-color", "red");
  }, function(){
  $("#sq_0").css("background-color", "green");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".but").click( function(){
  $("#sq_1").css("background-color", "red");
  }, function(){
  $("#sq_1").css("background-color", "green");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".but").click( function(){
  $("#sq_2").css("background-color", "red");
  }, function(){
  $("#sq_2").css("background-color", "green");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".but").click( function(){
  $("#sq_3").css("background-color", "red");
  }, function(){
  $("#sq_3").css("background-color", "green");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".but").click( function(){
  $("#sq_4").css("background-color", "red");
  }, function(){
  $("#sq_4").css("background-color", "green");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit' style='background:none; border:none;'>
<div style='margin: 6px;'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_0' style='width:30px; height:30px; background-color:red;' alt=''></div>
</div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit' style='background:none; border:none;'>
<div style='margin: 6px;'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_1' style='width:30px; height:30px; background-color:red;' alt=''></div>
</div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit' style='background:none; border:none;'>
<div style='margin: 6px;'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_2' style='width:30px; height:30px; background-color:red;' alt=''></div>
</div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit' style='background:none; border:none;'>
<div style='margin: 6px;'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_3' style='width:30px; height:30px; background-color:red;' alt=''></div>
</div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit' style='background:none; border:none;'>
<div style='margin: 6px;'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_4' style='width:30px; height:30px; background-color:red;' alt=''></div>
</div>
</button>
```

Comment: What it should be, when button is clicked only one should be green and on click of green it should be red again?

Comment: @Justcode That is correct, that is the function I'm looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(this).find('.here')` inside the click function to target the specific `div` of that `button`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".but").click(function() {
    $(this).find('.here').toggleClass('green');
  });
});
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit' style='background:none; border:none;'>
<div style='margin: 6px;'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_0' style='width:30px; height:30px; background-color:red;' alt=''></div>
</div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit' style='background:none; border:none;'>
<div style='margin: 6px;'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_1' style='width:30px; height:30px; background-color:red;' alt=''></div>
</div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit' style='background:none; border:none;'>
<div style='margin: 6px;'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_2' style='width:30px; height:30px; background-color:red;' alt=''></div>
</div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit' style='background:none; border:none;'>
<div style='margin: 6px;'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_3' style='width:30px; height:30px; background-color:red;' alt=''></div>
</div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit' style='background:none; border:none;'>
<div style='margin: 6px;'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_4' style='width:30px; height:30px; background-color:red;' alt=''></div>
</div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle a class with a green background using the `toggleClass` function.

Also, you should use the style in the classes you defined, and you can avoid the extra div wrapper, by adding the margin  to the `.here` class.

In this example all the buttons backgrounds will be changed:

```js
$(".but").click(function() {
  $(".here").toggleClass("clicked-here");
});
```

```css
.but {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.here {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 6px;
}

.clicked-here {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_0' alt=''></div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_1' alt=''></div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_2' alt=''></div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_3' alt=''></div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_4' alt=''></div>
</button>
```

And this will change only the clicked button:

```js
$(".but").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".here").toggleClass("clicked-here");
});
```

```css
.but {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.here {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 6px;
}

.clicked-here {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_0' alt=''></div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_1' alt=''></div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_2' alt=''></div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_3' alt=''></div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_4' alt=''></div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use jQuery class selector to selects all elements with the given class
[jQuery Class Selector (“.class”)](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Here is the example

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>class demo</title>
  <style>
  div, span {
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="notMe">div class="notMe"</div>
<div class="myClass">div class="myClass"</div>
<span class="myClass">span class="myClass"</span>
 
<script>
$( ".myClass" ).css( "border", "3px solid red" );
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to apply `!important` remove color from your styles and use the pure classes, get from  `$(this).find('.here')` and toggle the class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".but").click(function() {
    $(this).find('.here').toggleClass('green');
  });
});
```

```css
.here {
  background-color: red;
}

.here.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit' style='background:none; border:none;'>
<div style='margin: 6px;'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_0' style='width:30px; height:30px; ' alt=''></div>
</div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit' style='background:none; border:none;'>
<div style='margin: 6px;'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_1' style='width:30px; height:30px; ' alt=''></div>
</div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit' style='background:none; border:none;'>
<div style='margin: 6px;'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_2' style='width:30px; height:30px; ' alt=''></div>
</div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit' style='background:none; border:none;'>
<div style='margin: 6px;'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_3' style='width:30px; height:30px; ' alt=''></div>
</div>
</button>
<button class='but' type='submit' name='submit' style='background:none; border:none;'>
<div style='margin: 6px;'>
  <div class='here' id='sq_4' style='width:30px; height:30px; ' alt=''></div>
</div>
</button>
```